# chess-like rectangles on the mesh

Tags: mesh

I am new to concepts in CG. What are the red and white rectangles trying to represent in the following screenshot?

[image]

The image is from the paper "MoSh: Motion and Shape Capture from Sparse Markers".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's trying to represent anything in particular.

In CG there is a concept of textures, which is a bit like painting the surface of an object a specific color/look. For example, on a car you may want to paint scratches and dust on the surface.

Here they have created a human model from their capture data, and when visualising it they have decided to texture/paint a red/white checker pattern on top.

They have most likely added it for the viewer's benifit, as it helps emphasise the curves and overall shape of the model, esspesially as it animates. They also probably chose contrasting colors so the model was easier to view on a white background.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I was aware of concept of texture but was not sure why this paper and a couple more papers are using checkered pattern. It seemed weird to me but your explanation is right on!

Comment: I assume they needed something generalizable. Like they couldn't have real clothings or hair as it wouldn't be much generalizable and those need their own mesh. Specially that emphasize of paper was on body models not hair or clothing. I now actually find the checkered pattern an excellent and smart choice.

Comment: @MonaJalal it showcases the fact that the uv map is present. But also makes surface flow more apoarent